# CSS custom font only loads in Chrome

Tags: css, font-face, custom-font

I really don't know much about coding at all. So please bear with me. My company uses Vimeo OTT for our video streaming platform. Their templates are pretty awful and we are very limited to the changes we can make. I recently added our brand font to our site, and I thought it was working but we just noticed that our custom font only loads in chrome, but won't load in Safari or iOS/Android devices.

We have tried two different ways to incorporate the code (pasted below).
I have talked to multiple coders and they have all said both my code methods look right and should work.

Is there something that I am missing?

*Note, I have the same fonts loaded in our Squarespace site, so I am just downloading the fonts from the squarespace server.*

@import method

```
@import url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b48171945a3a215a7662/1596044417854/UnitedSansReg-Bold.woff2') ;

a.btn-site-primary, .btn-site-primary,.site-link-header-color, a.site-link-header-color:link, a.site-link-header-color:visited, .slide-title, .slide-button, .browse-row h1, .packages-head h1, h1.head.primary, .collection-title, .comment-count, .comment-count-language {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'UnitedSansReg-Bold' !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-format: woff2 !important;
}

@import url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b496c5f4ff2084e6c28e/1596044438306/UnitedSansReg-Light.woff2') ;

.cta--subscribe, .info--payment-details, .footer--site .helper-links a, .slide-subtitle span, .slide-description, .browse-item-title .subtext-container div, .see-more-link span, .see-more-row span, .browse-item-title strong, .btn-nowrap, .browse-item-subtext, .tooltip-description, h5, .comment-submit, .submit-comment-support-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'UnitedSansReg-Light' !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-format: woff2 !important;
}
```

@font-face method:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "UnitedSansReg-Bold" !important;
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21ac45c5f4ff2084e52867/1596042309239/UnitedSansReg-Bold.eot") !important;
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21a521f31c40507d5bcf04/1596040481708/UnitedSansReg-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b47bfb59025fbf301919/1596044411136/UnitedSansReg-Bold.woff") format(“woff”),
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b48171945a3a215a7662/1596044417854/UnitedSansReg-Bold.woff2") format(“woff2”),
url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5eebff3fd26de839fdd10b95/1592524607602/UnitedSansReg-Bold.otf") format("opentype") !important;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "UnitedSansReg-Light” !important;
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21ad8b94f7832d9b0ce766/1596042636037/UnitedSansReg-Light.eot") !important;
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21a563818afc02a1a333c7/1596040547396/UnitedSansReg-Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b494ba739a4d1d5c4ea9/1596044436254/UnitedSansReg-Light.woff") format(“woff”),
src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b496c5f4ff2084e6c28e/1596044438306/UnitedSansReg-Light.woff2") format(“woff2”),
url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59493973ccf210840b5b1e97/t/5ecfc18f529a4541ed266581/1590673807762/UnitedSansReg-Light.otf") format("opentype") !important;
}

a.btn-site-primary, .site-link-header-color, a.site-link-header-color:link, a.site-link-header-color:visited, .slide-title, .slide-button, .browse-row h1, .packages-head h1, h1.head.primary, .collection-title, .comment-count, .comment-count-language {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'UnitedSansReg-Bold' !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-format: opentype !important;
  font-format: woff !important;
  font-format: woff2 !important;
  font-format: truetype !important;
}

.cta--subscribe, .info--payment-details, .footer--site .helper-links a, .slide-subtitle span, .slide-description, .browse-item-title .subtext-container div, .see-more-link span, .see-more-row span, .browse-item-title strong, .btn-nowrap, .browse-item-subtext, .tooltip-description, h5, .comment-submit, .submit-comment-support-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'UnitedSansReg-Light' !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-format: opentype !important;
  font-format: woff !important;
  font-format: woff2 !important;
  font-format: truetype !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "UnitedSansReg-Bold";
    src: url("fonts/https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21ac45c5f4ff2084e52867/1596042309239/UnitedSansReg-Bold.eot");
    src: url("fonts/https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21ac45c5f4ff2084e52867/1596042309239/UnitedSansReg-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b48171945a3a215a7662/1596044417854/UnitedSansReg-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21b47bfb59025fbf301919/1596044411136/UnitedSansReg-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5eebff3fd26de839fdd10b95/1592524607602/UnitedSansReg-Bold.otf") format("opentype"),
         url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5eeac4a9e9957c6f6a19bb01/t/5f21a521f31c40507d5bcf04/1596040481708/UnitedSansReg-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

p {
    font-family: "UnitedSansReg-Bold";
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .eot file should be on its own src: url() for IE9 but the rest can be comma separated in one 'src' definition as demonstrated by Thomas.

There's a good chance you're just overriding a rule.
The !important on everything is probably making matters worse as well.

Comment: When I remove the !important's it reverts back to the template font.

Comment: Did you also remove all of the 'src' definitions and just use the 2 as suggested?